# Getting the sum per hour from 2 datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm writing a txt file from 2 data table.
Following is the 2 data table.

```
dt1
Transaction No.    Time         Amount     Date
    1              10:00:00     200.00     03/05/2020
    2              10:30:11     250.00     03/05/2020
    3              11:05:22     140.00     03/05/2020
    4              11:45:33     230.00     03/05/2020
    5              12:15:10     220.00     03/05/2020

dt2
Transaction No.    Added Amount   Date
    1              40.00          03/05/2020
    2              25.00          03/05/2020
    3              40.00          03/05/2020
    4              30.00          03/05/2020
    5              30.00          03/05/2020
```

*following is my code*

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName))
        {
            for (int a = 6; a <= 23; a++)
            {
                string aa = a.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');

                double salex = double.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString());
                if (salex.Equals(""))
                {
                    salex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    salex = double.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString());
                }

                double vatx = double.Parse(dt2.Rows[0]["Added Amount"].ToString());
                if (vatx.Equals(""))
                {
                    vatx = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    vatx = double.Parse(dt2.Rows[0]["Added Amount"].ToString());
                }

                double dailysaleHRLY = -salex + -vatx;

                sw.Write(dtpDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ",");
                sw.Write(aa + ":00" + ",");
                sw.Write(dailysaleHRLY.ToString("0.00") + ",");
            }

            for (int a = 0; a <= 5; a++)
            {
                string aa = a.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');                    
                double salex = double.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString());
                if (salex.Equals(""))
                {
                    salex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    salex = double.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["Amount"].ToString());
                }

                double vatx = double.Parse(dt2.Rows[0]["Added Amount"].ToString());
                if (vatx.Equals(""))
                {
                    vatx = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    vatx = double.Parse(dt2.Rows[0]["Added Amount"].ToString());
                }
                double dailysaleHRLY = -salex + -vatx;
                sw.Write(dtpDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ",");
                sw.Write(aa + ":00" + ",");
                sw.Write(dailysaleHRLY.ToString("0.00") + ",");
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Txt File succesfully created!", "SYSTEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

This is the output of my code.

> Date, Time, Sum 
>   03/05/2020,06:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,07:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,08:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,09:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,10:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,11:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,12:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,13:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,14:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,15:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,16:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,17:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,18:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,19:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,20:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,21:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,22:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,23:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,00:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,01:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,02:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,03:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,04:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,05:00,515.00

I just want to get the **sum** of **Amount** and **Added Amount** base on hour.
 Like this.

> Date, Time, Sum 
>   03/05/2020,06:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,07:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,08:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,09:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,10:00,515.00
>   03/05/2020,11:00,440.00
>   03/05/2020,12:00,250.00
>   03/05/2020,13:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,14:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,15:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,16:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,17:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,18:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,19:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,20:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,21:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,22:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,23:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,00:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,01:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,02:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,03:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,04:00,0.00
>   03/05/2020,05:00,0.00

Comment: `double sales` and then `sales.Equals("")` this will never be true. Does that code even compile?

Comment: LINQ? Join the 2 datatables on Transaction No. Gives some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two `DataTable-s` and you have them filled with the mentioned data.

```cs
var dt1 = new DataTable();
var dt2 = new DataTable();

dt1.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
    new DataColumn("Transaction No.", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Time", typeof(DateTime)),
    new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(decimal)),
    new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)),
});

dt2.Columns.AddRange(new[]
{
    new DataColumn("Transaction No.", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Added Amount", typeof(decimal)),
    new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)),
});
```

<sup>***Note:*** `The double` types have been replaced with `decimal` types since its the right type to be used when dealing with money.</sup>

As I understand the problem, you want to ***group*** the rows of `dt1` by *hour* part of the `Time` field, sum the `Amount`, and add to the sum the `Added Amount` from `dt2` rows where their `Transaction No.` equals to any `Transaction No.` of the grouped rows of `dt1`.

This will do:

```cs
var group = dt1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>(1).Hour);
var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("Date,");
sb.Append("Time,".PadLeft(12, ' '));
sb.AppendLine("Sum".PadLeft(5, ' '));

//if PadLeft is not required in the output, then just:
//sb.AppendLine($"Date, Time, Sum");

foreach (var g in group)
{
    var sum = 0M;
    foreach (var r in g)
        sum += r.Field<decimal>(2) + dt2.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.Field<int>(0) == r.Field<int>(0))
            .Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>(1));
    sb.AppendLine($"{g.First().Field<DateTime>(3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}, {g.Key.ToString("00")}:00, {sum.ToString("0.00")}");
}
```

<sup>**Note:** You can use the fields names instead of their indexes.</sup>

The output is:

```
Date,       Time,  Sum
03/05/2020, 10:00, 515.00
03/05/2020, 11:00, 440.00
03/05/2020, 12:00, 250.00
```

I don't know whether the `DataTable-s` already contain the required data to generate the output mentioned in the last quote block or you want to append the rest before writing to the text file. In case of the second scenario, you can do something like:

```cs
var group = dt1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>(1).Hour);
var sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine($"Date, Time, Sum");

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    var g = group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == i);

    if (g != null)
    {
        var sum = 0M;
        foreach (var r in g)
            sum += r.Field<decimal>(2) + dt2.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<int>(0) == r.Field<int>(0))
                .Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>(1));
        sb.AppendLine($"{g.First().Field<DateTime>(3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}, {g.Key.ToString("00")}:00, {sum.ToString("0.00")}");
    }
    else
        sb.AppendLine($"{group.First().First().Field<DateTime>(3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}, {i.ToString("00")}:00, 0.00");
}
```

If you need to preserve the same order of the hours:

```cs
for (var ii = 6; ii < 30; ii++)
{
    var i = ii > 23 ? ii % 24 : ii;
    var g = group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == i);

    if (g != null)
    {
    //The same...
}
```

Finally, to create or overwrite the text file (`fileName`):

```cs
File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());
```

Or to append the output:

```cs
File.AppendAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());
```